# Como saber quando o usuário abriu uma aplicação?

Tags: c#, windows

Como faço para verificar, enquanto o meu programa estiver rodando, se um determinado software é aberto pelo usuário?

Comment: Na versão em inglês você encontra uma um solução. Veja o link http://stackoverflow.com/a/967668/47733

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Filtrando pelos títulos das janelas**

Se você não souber ao certo qual é o nome da aplicação, e quiser, por exemplo usar o método `Contains` no nome da janela principal, poderia enumerar todos os processos em execução, e verificar quais deles atendem o seu critério.

```
while (true)
{
    var isOpen = Process.GetProcesses().Any(p =>
        p.MainWindowTitle.Contains("Microsoft"));

    if (isOpen)
        Console.WriteLine("Aplicação com titulo 'Microsoft' está aberta");

    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Se você souber o nome da aplicação, você pode usar a propriedade `ProcessName` ao invés do nome da janela.

**Como saber o nome de um processo**

É muito fácil de saber o nome dos processos, basta usar o Gerenciador de Tarefas do Windows (Ctrl + Shift + Esc), e ir na aba Processos... o nome é geralmente a primeira coluna que aparece, mas sem incluir a extensão. Se uma aplicação se chama `devenv.exe`, basta usar "devenv" como o nome no seu código:

```
while (true)
{
    var isOpen = Process.GetProcesses().Any(p =>
        p.ProcessName == "devenv");

    if (isOpen)
        Console.WriteLine("Aplicação com titulo 'Microsoft' está aberta");

    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo, obrigado!

Answer (score 7):

Uma solução é verificar os processos que estão abertos em uma thread e procurar qual a determinada aplicação que você está verificando.

Um exemplo bem simples para verificar quando o usuário abriu a calculadora do Windows (cujo nome do processo é `calc`):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("calc");

                if (pname.Length != 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("A calculadora foi aberta as " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt"));
                    break;
                }
                else 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("A calculadora ainda não foi aberta.");
                }

                Thread.Sleep(200);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Note que `Process.GetProcessesByName()` está em `System.Diagnostics` e `Thread.Sleep()` está em `System.Threading`. O `Thread.Sleep(200)` (nesse caso) foi para dar uma folga para a CPU (não é crítico verificar se a calculadora foi aberta a cada ms).